# Do you get an easy to use IIS Installer?

Tags: iis, installation

I have just finished the development of a web service application in visual studio.

Is there an easy way to wrap it in an installer, so that I can just ship it off to technical support, and they can have a wizard based installer that will fully setup an IIS site for them, either in 6 or 7?

Comment: Have you looked at Web Deployment Projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio's built in setup project. I've only tried this once on a test project, but it created all the necessary stuff in IIS 6 just fine.

Comment: It works for what I need it to do, not over complicated, but takes a bit of getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you export the IIS METABASE for your local instance of the service and then this can be imported into a new server to create the correct IIS configuration. Have a look at [Copying IIS Configurations using iiscnfg.vbs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739803%28WS.10%29.aspx) The METABASE is just an XML file and you will easily see the specific values that allows you to edit them should the deployment be different in anyway.